# поиск и устранение несоответствий в датафреймах

Tags: r

```
library(quantmod)
library(rusquant)
library(tseries)
library(timeDate)

startDate <- as.Date('2018-01-01')
endDate <- as.Date('2020-04-14')

tickers <- c("TATN", "TATNP")

getSymbols(tickers, src = 'Finam', period = '30min', from = startDate, to = endDate)

TATN <- data.table(time = index(TATN$TATN.Open), TATN$TATN.Open, TATN$TATN.Close)
TATNP <- data.table(time = index(TATNP$TATNP.Open), TATNP$TATNP.Open, TATNP$TATNP.Close)
```

Я скачиваю котировки акций с финама и сталкиваюсь с проблемой потери части данных по одной из бумаг.
в примере кода скачиваются данные по ценам с шагом в 30 минут, и в итоге я получаю фреймы разной длинны, так как в одном из фреймов теряется одна и более котировок, что приводит к разной длинне полученных данных
Например в моем коде тикер TATN имеет длинну 10366 , а TATNP имеет длинну 10364 , соответственно выпало 2 котировки.

Что бы устранить эту проблему мне нужно найти данные которые не соответствуют, а именно тот индекс времени который присутствует в одном фрейме и отсутствует в другом и удалить его, что бы этого времени и соответствующего этому времени данных не было сразу в двух датафреймах, а остались только те котировки, которые имеют одинаковый индекс времени.

Как я могу решить эту задачу?

Пример данных в таблице по ссылке

https://yadi.sk/d/dr0W3UO_U91nSA

Comment: вы бы пример данных (TATN и TATNP) привели (нажав [edit]). десять тысч, конечно, не надо. двух-трёх вполне достаточно. и, конечно, нужен желаемый результат. а код, который вы привели, кстати, вообще не нужен. [mcve]

Comment: Добавил таблицу с примером данных в которых наблюдается отсутствие одного временного промежутка в последовательности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

так как примера данных не предоставлено, приведу абстрактный пример.

допустим, есть две `data.table`:

```
> t1 <- data.table(c(1, 2, 4), 1:3)
> t1
   V1 V2
1:  1  1
2:  2  2
3:  4  3
> t2 <- data.table(c(1, 2, 3, 5), 5:8)
> t2
   V1 V2
1:  1  5
2:  2  6
3:  3  7
4:  5  8
```

получить только те строки из `t1`, в которых `V1` совпадает с `V1` из `t2`:

```
> t1[V1 %in% t2$V1]
   V1 V2
1:  1  1
2:  2  2
```

и взаимообразно, получить только те строки из `t2`, в которых `V1` совпадает с `V1` из `t1`:

```
> t2[V1 %in% t1$V1]
   V1 V2
1:  1  5
2:  2  6
```

Comment: `t1 <- data.table(c('2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05'), c(23.3, 25.6, 24.7, 26.3))
t2 <- data.table(c('2020-04-01', '2020-04-02', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05'), c(21.6, 23.5, 20.1, 27.9))`

нужно в двух таблицах разной длинны найти те даты (столбцы V1 в примере), которые присутствуют только в одном из фреймов и удалить их, так что бы фреймы стали одинаковой длинны

Comment: что-то не получилось?

Comment: в Вашем примере фреймы имеют одинаковую длинну, но основная проблема состоит в том, что фреймы разной длинны и мне нужно их привести к одной длинне путем удаления той строки в одном фрейме , которой нет в другом фрейме

Comment: да, действительно, надо оператор `%in%` применять, а не `==`. исправил ответ.